# NFS mount properties (options) in FreeBSD

Tags: freebsd, nfs

I am trying to determine how to examine the actual properties of an NFS mount in FreeBSD. In CentOS (6.4 tested) one can `cat /proc/mounts` or execute `nfsstat -m` to determine all of the mount properties. Specifically I am trying to determine why on a FreeBSD VM I have 3 times better performance on an NFS mount than on a CentOS VM.

My `fstab` on FreeBSD is:

```
server:/share /mountpoint nfs rw 00
```

What this implies for other options. What are the default options?

Comment: Does FreeBSD then not have nfsstat?

Comment: FreeBSD provides nfsstat but does not provide the -m switch

Comment: @strimpak - The -m option [appears to have been added in December 2012](https://svnweb.freebsd.org/base?view=revision&revision=243783). Also, the [man page](http://man.freebsd.org/mount_nfs) is pretty good about listing defaults.

Answer (score 2):

Use "nfsstat -m" on the client machine.  It will show something like this:

```
# nfsstat -m        
localhost:/ on /net/localhost
nfsv3,tcp,resvport,hard,intr,cto,lockd,sec=sys,acdirmin=3,acdirmax=60,acregmin=5,ac
regmax=60,nametimeo=60,negnametimeo=60,rsize=65536,wsize=65536,readdirsize=65536,re
adahead=1,wcommitsize=8388608,timeout=120,retrans=2
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try the `-p` option to mount on FreeBSD?

```
$ mount -p
```

*excerpt from mount man page*

```
 -p      Print mount information in fstab(5) format.  Implies also the -v
     option.
```

#### References

- [FreeBSD mount man page](http://www.manpages.info/freebsd/mount.8.html)

Comment: mount -p displays information that is available in /etc/fstab. I will give an example:`
# mount -p
server:/share /mountpoint         nfs     rw              0 0 `